# Refresh marquee on finish of text/Onfinish event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Browser:Chrome
I am getting text for marquee from xml file.  Can somebody help how to refresh the html page and get updated xml on finishing scrolling all previous data.
i.e. the **onfinish event for marquee in chrome browser**.
Thanks..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="bloc2" style="position: absolute; left:113px; top:9px; background-color: lightgrey; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 30px; margin: 0px;" >
<marquee id="testone" scrolldelay=100 loop=1 style="margin-top:0px;" ></marquee>
</div>

<script>
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "xml/News.xml", true);
xhttp.send();


function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i,y,j,txt,text,xmlDoct; 


    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("JobName");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
    }
    document.getElementById("testone").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `marquee` element is about 100 years old and is not standard HTML. It has been deprecated and should not be used. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: You should use CSS Transitions instead of `marquee`.

Comment: Can you please provide me css marquee or jquery marquee with onfinish event working on Chrome. Thanks!!

Comment: Chrome and CSS3 are broken in this regard, avoid them